# AWS AssumeRole account id issue with multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have recently taken over from a DevOps staffer, thrown in the deep end and am having trouble running any code that interacts with AWS. At the most basic level what has changed is that I have been added to the admin role, under our master account id, without giving it away let's assume it's 111111. I previously ran code (NodeJS / NestJS) which retrieves AWS parameter store entries from an account with id 222222 (our dev account), without a problem. Now, however, I get the following error when trying to run the code:

> User: arn:aws:iam::111111:user/my.account is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameters on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:111111:parameter/platform/master/hostname with an explicit deny

In my ~/.aws/config file I specifically say:

```
[default]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::222222:role/DeveloperRestrictedRole
source_profile = mfa_creds
region = us-west-2
output = json

[profile my_profile]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::222222:role/DeveloperRestrictedRole
source_profile = mfa_creds
region = us-west-2
output = json
```

In the ~/.aws/credentials file I have the mfa_creds section specified.

When I run the following from a command prompt it works. So, it looks like the problem is that the code is not picking up the correct account id, even though it is specified in the config file. The following command works from the command line:

`aws ssm get-parameter --name "/platform/master/hostname"`

This command works as well:

`aws ssm get-parameter --name "/platform/master/hostname" --profile my_profile`

Have searched through the codebase and the account id is nowhere to be found in code, all the config items get pulled automatically from the AWS param store, which is initialised with:

`AwsConfig.update({ region: "us-west-2" });
this.ssm = new SSM();`

Happy to get some guidance and things to try, I'm at a bit of a loss with this one, since my user account has always existed in the master account and I've always been able to run the code, until I was added to the admin role / group. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, whoever did that, maybe leave a comment next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, thanks john-rotenstein for putting me on the right path, and guiding my search criteria to get this fixed :-)

This worked for me:

1. Setting the environment variable by using `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`, this can also be set to "true", both work. I already had this in place and auto-loaded for my default shell (bash_profile). Windows users will have to set this via the "My Computer -> Properties"
2. Setting the environment variable `export AWS_PROFILE="my_profile"` and making sure it was in my bash_profile, I did not have this originally, I ran this in a standard mac os terminal window, and added it to my bash profile
3. Making sure that my developer IDE (Visual Studio Code) had access to both environment variables in the **new** terminal window by running `set | grep AWS` - this was reporting only the existing AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG environment variable, even after closing the terminal window and opening a new one. I fixed this by manually running the export command in the VS code terminal window as I did not want to restart the machine, which should also have fixed it

Hope someone finds this useful!

Answer (score 2):

When you run from the CLI, it is assuming the role in Account 2.

When you are running the code, it is using credentials from Account 1 (without assuming the role).

I think (not 100% sure) that the ability to assume a role in the `~.aws/config` file is a feature of the AWS CLI, but not a feature of using credentials via a normal AWS SDK.

So, your code will need to specifically **assume the role in Account 2**, then use the returned credentials to call the services in Account 2.

Comment: Thanks for the info :-) Strange though, and not easy to do as the codebase is shared amongst a dozen other developers who have to ensure the same profile name. I would have assumed the fact that the "default" in config file was set the same (and the AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 env var is set) would have made the SDK look at the same thing the CLI is...